# Source a file from rust using Command

Tags: rust, command-line-interface

I am using the Command crate to source a file. I am doing a `ls -a`using the same Command crate before I source. The file that is to be sourced is present when I list directory contents. But when I source I get a file not found error.

**Error and log:**

```
     Running `target/debug/alias_cli h htop`
.       .alias      Cargo.lock  src
..      .idea       Cargo.toml  target
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to source alias file: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', libcore/result.rs:1009:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
./.alias%
```

**Code:**

```
fn source_alias_file(alias_file: &String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    print!("{}", alias_file);
    Command::new("ls")
        .arg("-a")
        .spawn()
        .expect("Failed to list");

    Command::new("source")
        .arg(alias_file)
        .spawn()
        .expect("Failed to source alias file");

    Ok(())
}
```

What is going wrong here?

I am able to source the file directly from the terminal without any errors.

Answer (score 3):

[`source`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) is a bash command, it's not a program so you can't invoke it like that you need to use bash:

```
Command::new("bash")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg(format!("source {}", alias_file))
    .spawn()
    .expect("Failed to source alias file");
```

Comment: wouldn't this create a new bash session which would terminate as soon as the `Command` will also terminate. This will mean only within that session the file will be sourced.

Comment: @leoOrion I'm unaware of what this command do. But yes this will do that.

Comment: I am looking for a way to source a file within the same session that I call `cargo run` from

Comment: @leoOrion It's not possible by design